# WSLのフォルダにアクセスできない「アクセスできません このネットワークリソースを使用するアクセス許可がない可能性があります」

Tags: windows, wsl

Windows10で、WSLをインストールして、WSLのフォルダにエクスプローラーからアクセスしようとしました。

エクスプローラーに「\wsl$」と入力し、Ubuntuが表示されました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
しかし、このフォルダをダブルクリックで開こうとすると、「アクセスできません このネットワークリソースを使用するアクセス許可がない可能性があります」というメッセージが表示され、開けません。

[ネットワーク共有センターの「パスワード保護共有を無効にする」](https://aprico-media.com/posts/5997)を試してみたのですが、影響はなく、エクスプローラーからは開けないままでした。

WSLのフォルダにエクスプローラーからアクセスして、ファイルを編集したりすることは出来ないのでしょうか？

Comment: 確認してみてください: https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#cannot-access-wsl-files-from-windows

Answer (score 1):

同じ現象がありました。
エクスプローラーのアドレスバーに『\\wsl$』を入力すると、とりあえず開きました。
エクスプローラーのネットワークのアイコンを押したら、ポップアップ画面がでてきた。そして、許可したらアクセスできるようになった。